# How do I get the list of bad records that didn't load in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to get all the *bad records* that get skipped while doing a Bigquery load job and setting *--max_bad_records* ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the status.errors field will have a list of errors that occurred during job processing, including non-fatal errors like bad rows that were skipped.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs