# How to skip records during appending to table when column is NULL but was REQUIRED?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to skip rows during querying data to table which have NULL values on REQUIRED column.

Now whole query is failing.

I would like to have similar behaviour to
the flag [configuration.load.maxBadRecords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) which is only for JSON/CSV.
It skips bad records and according to [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861881/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-bad-records-that-didnt-load-in-bigquery) stores bad records in status.errors field.

I didn't test above flag but I see that it is connected with configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues and could be probably useful when records are not able to being parsed (eg. due to invalid characters)

Anyway in my case error is caused by NULL values when they are REQUIRED?

I would be grateful also for some reasonable workarounds.
For me setting default values by IFNULL is not the option.
I want also avoid detect such rows programatically.

Comment: I don't understand--why is using IFNULL or filtering rows that contain NULL values not an option?

Comment: IFNULL is not an option for me because I cannot set default values due to contract. Regarding filtering rows - it would have great impact on our processing logic, we want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I think filtering using SQL is your best option.

Comment: Looks that we have no choice, thanks for opinion!